Simplification of Dependent Nested Integrals
I have been working with nested Integrals of the following form :
$$ \int_0^{T}dt_n \int_0^{t_n}dt_{n-1} \cdot \cdot \cdot \int_0^{t_2} dt_1 \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(t_i) $$
Some simpler cases and prework :
I found somewhat easily that if each $f_i$ are the same then for the case n=2, using some integral tricks it can be easily found that
$$ \int_0^{T}dt_2 \int_0^{t_2} dt_1 f(t_2) f(t_1) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \int_0^T dt f(t) \right) ^2 $$
and then later for a more general n, with each $f_i$ still equivalent ,
$$ \int_0^{T}dt_n \int_0^{t_n}dt_{n-1} \cdot \cdot \cdot \int_0^{t_2} dt_1 \prod_{i=1}^n f(t_i) = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\int_0^T dt f(t) \right)^n$$
Question :
I now wonder for the extremely general case if it is possible to simplify the first expression when each $f_i$ is a different function, or perhaps if two or more are the same. In particular I wonder about the case of n=3 at the moment, with hopes to move into higher orders afterwards, but i cant seem to see a way to simplify this into perhaps, a product of integrals, or some other simplification, and was hoping someone with a better background in mathematics could help steer me in the right direction. Thanks

I don't think there is closed-form expression for the general case $f_i \ne f_j$.

... Another approach for the case $f_i = f$ is
$$I=\int_{0\le t_1  \le t_2\le  ...\le t_n \le T}\prod_{i=1}^nf(t_i)dt_1...dt_n$$
We observe that the value of the integral $I$ doesn't change when we switch any variable $i$ and $j$, for example
$$I=\int_{0\le \color{red}{t_2  \le t_1}\le  ...\le t_n \le T}\prod_{i=1}^nf(t_i)dt_1...dt_n$$
...

(continue)...
There are in total $n!$ permutations $\sigma:{1,..,n} \mapsto {1,..,n}$, so
$$\begin{align}
n! \cdot I &=\sum_{\text{permutation } \sigma} \int_{0\le t_{\sigma(1)}  \le t_{\sigma(2)}\le  ...\le t_{\sigma(n)} \le T}\prod_{i=1}^nf(t_i)dt_1...dt_n\
&=\int_{0\le t_1 \le T\0\le t_2\le T\...\0\le t_n\le T}\prod_{i=1}^nf(t_i)dt_1...dt_n\
& = \left(\int_0^T f(t)dt \right)^n
\end{align}$$
